# ADD database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql

Tags: codeigniter, docker

I want to install opensourcepos with the help of docker. when i run docker-compose up command its shows me following error.

Step 3/4 : ADD database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql

ERROR: Service 'sqlscript' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder784255971/database.sql: no such file or directory

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    uploads:
        driver: local
    logs:
        driver: local

networks:
    app_net:
    db_net:

services:
    sqlscript:
        build:
            context: database/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ospos:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: ospos
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - mysql
        expose:
          - "80"
        networks:
          - app_net
          - db_net
        volumes:
          - uploads:/app/public/uploads
          - logs:/app/application/logs
        environment:
          - FORCE_HTTPS=true
          - PHP_TIMEZONE=UTC
          - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
          - MYSQL_DB_NAME=ospos
          - MYSQL_HOST_NAME=mysql

    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.3
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        expose:
          - "3306"
        networks:
          - db_net
        volumes_from:
          - sqlscript
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= password
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=ospos
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - mysql
        expose:
          - "80"
        networks:
          - app_net
          - db_net
        environment:
          - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= password
          - PMA_HOST=mysql

    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.15-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - ospos
          - phpmyadmin
          - certbot
        volumes:
          - ./docker/data/nginx/nginx.tmpl:/etc/nginx/nginx.tmpl:ro
          - ./docker/data/nginx/error_log.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
          - ./docker/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
          - ./docker/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot:ro
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "8000:8000"
        networks:
          - app_net
        environment:
          - WEB_DOMAIN= localhost
          - ESC=$$
        command: "/bin/sh -c 'envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.tmpl > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf & while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot
        container_name: certbot
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./docker/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
          - ./docker/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        networks:
          - app_net
        entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

Docker File

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
MAINTAINER jekkos

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    openssl

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli bcmath intl gd
RUN echo "date.timezone = \"\${PHP_TIMEZONE}\"" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/timezone.ini
RUN echo -e “$(hostname -i)\t$(hostname) $(hostname).localhost” >> /etc/hosts

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN ln -s /app/*[^public] /var/www && rm -rf /var/www/html && ln -nsf /app/public /var/www/html
RUN chmod 755 /app/public/uploads && chown -R www-data:www-data /app/public /app/application

RUN [ ! -f test/ospos.js ] || sed -i -e "s/\(localhost\)/web/g" test/ospos.js
```

Both the files are in same directory.

Comment: Are you sure `database.sql` exists in the same directory as `dockerfile`

Comment: yes database.sql exist in same directory where docker-compose file exist

Comment: please provide dockerfile and docker-compose in the question

Comment: when you say `context: database/` the docker-compose will search `database.sql` in that `database` folder. Does `database.sql` exists in `database` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
ADD database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql
```

and move `database.sql` to database folder

Comment: where should i added it. LinPy

Comment: where do you have this `Step 3/4 : ADD database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql` this should be replaced

Comment: i have another Docker file in database folder which have following content.

FROM alpine
MAINTAINER jekkos

ADD database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql
VOLUME /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

when i replace the code then its shos me this error.

Step 3/4 : ADD ../database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql
ERROR: Service 'sqlscript' failed to build: ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../database.sql ()